# Simple notification on program completion

Tags: ssh

I'm running something while ssh'ed into a machine (through mosh). I would use sendmail to get a notification on termination of a program, but this machine cannot connect to the network for security reasons.

Is there any way I can get a notification on my local machine once the program terminates?

Edit:
Specifically, once I've logged in on the remove machine, I would like to have a notification of some sort on the local machine while staying in the same ssh session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to send the mail from the foreign machine.  The local machine can send an email on command completion:

```
ssh host cmd ; echo "It's done." | mail me@somewhere -s Completion
```

If you must stay logged in on the remote machine, you can still monitor its command's progress.  As an example:

```
$ ssh host 'cmd1 ; echo Done $?; cmd2' | { while read a b; do [ "$a" = "Done" ] && echo "It's done with code $b." | mail me@somewhere -s Completion; done; }
```

In the above, `cmd1 ; echo Done $?; cmd2` is run on the remote computer.  With the `while` loop, the local computer monitors the progress and sends you an email when `cmd1` has completed.

Comment: @bear This is now updated with a stay-logged-in solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple solutions to notify locally at the end of a script, here are two:

Use the beep character at the end, that gives an audible sound:

```
ssh user@host /path/to/script; echo -e '\a' > $(tty)
```

You can eject the CD-drive (my favorite; it doesn't matter what you do, you'll be noticed :-). Also if you go away and come back or lock the machine, you'll see it.)

```
ssh user@host /path/to/script; eject
```

Comment: Hahaha I love the creativity, but I meant that once I've logged in on the remove machine, I would like to have a notification of some sort on the local machine while staying in the same ssh session.

Comment: @bear _"once I've logged in on the remove machine"_  I take it that you don't have publlic key authentication set up.  If you did, then logging in and out becomes a trivial matter, one hardly worth a moment's thought.

Comment: I do have that set up, but we require 2fac auth, so Id have to tap a yubikey -- quite more than a moment's thought!

Comment: @bear - You can still use these suggestions, the first will work as is *(though the `>$(tty)` bit isn't strictly necessary)*, except that you would login first w/ `mosh user@host`; then rather than do `ssh ...;` you'd do `your command;printf \\a` and you'll get your beep. The second you could do much the same, except that instead of just `eject`, you might want `ssh you@local eject` to log back into your local machine from the remote session and run the `eject` command. Oh. but no network, right. So the beep works anyway, for `eject` you'd need to setup a shell trap first.